# Modifying Django's ORM query in a loop

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

G'day 
I'm struggling with modyfing/extending query in Django. Let's say I have query like this one below:

```
query_set = Managers.objects.select_related('managers_contacts').all()
```

and now I'd like to use a Python's loop to go through a dictionary which might looks like: `{'continent': 'North America', 'country': '', 'city': ''}` in case of some key is not none the query set should be extended by: .`filter(managers_addresses__some_field='')`
I now how to build the loop but there problem is how add .filter() object to existed query set? Using class? Do You have any suggestions At the end I'd like to get something like

```
query_set = Managers.objects.select_related('managers_contacts').all().filter(managers_addresses__some_field='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack arguments from dict using ** syntax. 
So you just need to create new dict and fill it with correct keys names:

```
# Python 3.6 or above
kwargs = {f"managers_addresses__{key}": value for key, value in some_dict.items() if value}
queryset = queryset.filter(**kwargs)

# Python 3.5 or lower
kwargs = {"managers_addresses__{}".format(key): value for key, value in some_dict.items() if value}
queryset = queryset.filter(**kwargs)
```